# Using .Include with criteria

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a Verse class which has a list of VerseTranslation.

When I fetch the verse I only want some of the verse translations. Is there a way to do something like this?

```
var desiredTranslationCodes = new List<string> { "Code1", "Code2" }; 
var result = Context.Verses.Where(v => v.Chapter == 1 && v.VerseNumber == 3)
  .Include(v => v.Translations, t => desiredTranslationCodes.Contains(t.TranslatorCode))
```

I am only going to convert these to a view model. It seems a big waste to load all VerseTranslations when I might only want 2 of the 10 translations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use projections to anonymous or new type. Try the following. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
var result  = Context.Verses.Select(c => new 
{ 
    Data = c, 
    Translations = c.Translations.OrderBy(p => p.Name).Take(2) 
});
```